# Exposing https rest full web service in oracle service bus

Tags: java, osb, oracle-service-bus, oracle-soa, soa-suite

I need help to expose a rest web service on https, I have done it on http by selecting http protocol. When I check https required on transport level configuration with authentication none. It is giving 0 NO RESPONSE .

Any body have solution to do or any tutorial which I can follow please let me know.

Comment: Can you update the question with code that you have done  or tried to resolve the issue?

Comment: I have just checked https required in transport configuration with basic authentication none. but when calling no response.